# Is a contagious Muslim exempt from Haj?

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, hajj

It seems that Saudi Arabia is denying men from Ebola-infected areas entry:

- http://www.aljazeera.com/news/africa/2014/08/guinea-west-africa-ebola-havoc-worst-hit-death-toll-dis-2014817221533942276.html

Assuming the worst case, if a man *has the Ebola virus* is he exempt from Haj or must he still perform the pilgrimage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prophet is reported to have said =

> "Plague was a means of torture sent on a group of Israelites. So if
>   you hear of its spread in a land, don't approach it, and if a plague
>   should appear in a land where you are present, then don't leave that
>   land in order to run away from it."

[[Sahih al-Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/140)

So from this narration, we can say that it's not obligatory until the person gets better.  And as Ali said, the person can be putting others lives in danger.

InshaAllah the person who's infected with ebola will be rewarded for his/her intention to do hajj.

Answer (score 2):

The Hajj is not mandatory for a person who does not have the Health, Wealth and means to go to Hajj...

Actually in some cases, scholars say it is highly un-recommended for one to do Hajj, if it endangers his own life or the life of others.

I am not a scholar, but from my understanding; this would be that case where Hajj is even forbidden or highly un-recommended on the Person who is Sick.

Especially an Ebola patient, because he can potentially endanger thousands of other people.

Comment: Thank you Ali. Have you a link to the proper Hadith? I would need that to accept the answer. Thank you very much.